# Bootstrap nav links are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3.3.7 and using nav bar of bootstrap. I want menu should toggle when using tab key. Below code is workign fine but due to this after opening the menu links define inside it not working.

Note:- Using tab and then click on link not working. Using mouse and click on link working.

```
$(".main-nav a").on("keydown", function () {  
        $(this).next().dropdown("toggle");
});
```

Code below

```
    <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default main-nav">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="hello.html">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>


  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
      $(".main-nav a").on("keydown", function() {
          $(this).next().dropdown("toggle");
        });
  </script>
</body>
```

Above is the complete code, using tab the nav opens on keydown that is my requirement. But due to this links are not working.

Comment: Can you please explain the issue further that what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<style>
.marginBottom-0 {margin-bottom:0;}

.dropdown-submenu{position:relative;}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{top:0;left:100%;margin-top:-6px;margin-left:-1px;-webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;}
.dropdown-submenu>a:after{display:block;content:" ";float:right;width:0;height:0;border-color:transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;border-left-color:#cccccc;margin-top:5px;margin-right:-10px;}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after{border-left-color:#555;}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left{float:none;}.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu{left:-100%;margin-left:10px;-webkit-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;}

</style>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top marginBottom-0" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 3</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Link 4</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>

<script>
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            event.stopPropagation(); 
            $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not i am looking for.